# Bootstrap column is cutting off the left edge of my rows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a python/flask/html project I'm currently working on. I'm using bootstrap 4 for a grid system with multiple rows and columns. When I try to run my project, it cuts off a few pixels on the left side of the screen. I've looked all over my code and I'm still not sure as to why this is. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mk78ebo2/) is a jsfiddle with my code, as well as a hard copy of it. Thank you for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<!-- Link to css file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/main.css" mesdia="screen"/>

<!-- Bootstrap CDN-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Layout</title>
<!--<h1>Welcome to the layout</h1>
<p>Where would you like to navigate to?</p>-->
```

```
<div class="row" id="navcols">

    <div class="col">
        <div class="row h-50">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-50">Row</div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">Row</div>
    </div>

</div>

<!--
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 id="test">Welcome to my page! Where do you want to navigate to?</h1>
</div>-->
```

```
    html,body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as Bootstrap layout is concerned, you always need to put your row and col elements within a div with the class of  **container** or **container-fluid**.
If you want full width column then use **container-fluid**. **container** has a max width pixel value, whereas .**container-fluid** is max-width 100%. .**container-fluid** continuously resizes as you change the width of your window/browser by any amount. :

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row" id="navcols">

    <div class="col">
      <div class="row h-50">Row</div>
      <div class="row h-50">Row</div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
      <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
      <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
      <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
      <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">Row</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your row class div inside of a container or container-fluid class div

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <!--your grid-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add .container OR .container-fluid class in parent div in your HTML.

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row" id="navcols">

    <div class="col">
        <div class="row h-50">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-50">Row</div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">Row</div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Bootstrap class contains -15px margin from left and right; that's why it is cutting your screen. So, you can fix it by making it 0.

```
<div class="row" id="navcols" style="margin-left:0; margin-right:0;">

    <div class="col">
        <div class="row h-50">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-50">Row</div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
        <div class="row h-100">Row</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">Row</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: I added a picture for you. have a look.